# Axios POST to Laravel API results in 419 error

Tags: laravel, nuxt.js

I'm trying to send a POST request with axios to my API which is running Laravel but i got a 419 error Token mismatch exception

I send the request with axios in Nuxtjs

```
async register(){

            await axios.get('http://localhost:8000/sanctum/csrf-cookie');

            await this.$axios.post('http://localhost:8000/api/register', {
                data: {
                    name: this.pseudo,
                    email: this.email,
                    password: this.password,
                    password_confirmation: this.confirmationPassword
                },
                headers: {
                    'x-csrf-token': document.querySelector("[name=csrf-token]").getAttribute('content'),
                }
            })
            this.$router.push("/");
        }
```

I've looked for the solution everywhere on the web but i didn't find it.

Thanks

Comment: You can set the header like that:
`axios.defaults.headers.post['X-CSRF-Token'] = document.querySelector("[name=csrf-token]").getAttribute('content');`

Comment: Thanks for your answer but i have an error.

document is not defined. 

I use server side rendering so maybe it's because of this ?