# How to get Laravel CSRF value in NEXTJS

Tags: laravel, next.js, csrf

I have a Next JS frontend and Laravel 9 as backend. Created APIs and tested them on the postman. All of the API's working fine without any issues.

**The Problem**

So I have created a Nextjs file with a form and posted data using Axios. I am getting `Error: Request failed with status code 419`.

**Tried**

There are multiple answers available on StackOverflow for similar questions. I followed the answers but nothing worked for the problem.

1. Changed VerifyCsrfToken.php code to disable the csrf protection. (i
   want to keep the csrf)
2. Tried adding the csrf cookie using the headers option in Axios.
   ([Axios POST to Laravel API results in 419 error](https://stackoverflow.com/q/70830662/17486591))
3. Generated key using (PHP artisan key: generate)
4. Added Session domain
5. added route in the web middleware

```
Route::group(['middleware' => ['api']], function () {

    // our routes

});
```

**What's working ?**

1. Allowing all domains in VerifyCsrfToken.php is working.

**I want to get csrf token**

`const csrf = () => axios.get('/sanctum/csrf-cookie')'

i am getting empty value for csrf token / csrf cookie. and found no accepted answer to the request failed with status code 419.

Does anyone know what I am doing wrong?

Comment: How to work with the CSRF really depends on your app. For example I have a script in my main page layout like `<script>window.csrfToken = "{{csrf_token()}}";</script>` and whenever i POST something to my backend I always need to add field `_token: window.csrfToken` but there's literally hundreds of ways to get this to work as long as you pass the token from your backend to your frontend somehow and then remember to send it back to the backend it should work.

Comment: can you please share a way to add csfr using nextjs frontend for laravel backend.

Comment: If you are not already, use [Sanctum](https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/sanctum#introduction) in your backend and set it up such that `const csrf = () => axios.get('/sanctum/csrf-cookie')'` works i.e. set it up for SPA authentication. If you do already use Sanctum and /sanctum/csrf-cookie doesn't work then you probably misconfigured it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As per the documentation of laravel :

**Do these 3 changes in Laravel**

1. Update the cors policy (config/cors.php)

From : `'supports_credentials' => false,`

To: `'supports_credentials' => true,`

2. Add the line in (resources/js/bootstrap.js)

`axios.defaults.withCredentials = true;`

3. Add backend and frontend url in .env file in laravel

```
APP_URL=http://localhost:8000
FRONTEND_URL=http://localhost:3000
```

**Now do the following cahnges in NEXT JS app.**

1. Add .env.local file at the root and add the following code.
   `NEXT_PUBLIC_BACKEND_URL=http://localhost:8000'`
2. Install axios using `npm i axios`
3. Import CSRF Token using AXIOS before posting the data using axios then post form data using axios.

**Here is the sample code to send or get data**

```
import React, { useEffect, useState } from 'react';
import axios from 'axios';

//optional toastify library
import { ToastContainer, toast } from 'react-toastify';
import 'react-toastify/dist/ReactToastify.css';

export default function index({data}) {

//console.log(data); 

  //setting the state (getting form data into veriable)
  const [title, setTitle] = useState('')
  const [desc, setDesc] = useState('')

  
  // preventing default and showing the data in console
  const formSubmit = async (e) => {
  e.preventDefault();
  console.log(title ,desc);

      // setting csrf token
       await axios.get('http://localhost:8000/sanctum/csrf-cookie').then(getcsrvf => {
                
          //console.log(getcsrvf);
            
                 // posting the data using axios / creating the data.
                  axios.post('http://localhost:8000/api/post', {title,desc})
                  .then(function (response) {
                    //alert(response.data.message);
                    
                   toast(response.data.message);
                    
                    console.log(response);
                  })
                  .catch(function (error) {
                    //console.log(error);
                  });
          });
} 


  return (

// bootstrap installed

<div className=' pt-5'>
<div className='container'>

//basic jsx form

<form onSubmit={formSubmit}> 

 <div className='mb-2'> 

{/* onChange={(e)=>{setName(e.target.value)}} */}

<input type="text" onChange={(e) => {setTitle(e.target.value)}} value={title} className="form-control mb-2 py-2" placeholder="title" name="title" id='title' />

</div>  

<div className='mb-2'>
<input type="text" onChange={(e) => {setDesc(e.target.value)}} value={desc} className="form-control mb-2 py-2" placeholder="desc" name="desc" id='desc' />
</div>  


<div className='mb-2'>
<button className='btn btn-primary'>Submit</button>
</div>  
</form> 

</div>


<hr/>
//looping the post data

{data.post.map((post, i)=>{
  return (
    <div className='container' key={i}>
      <h3>{post.title}</h3>
      <p>{post.desc}</p>
      <hr/>
    </div>
  )
})}


<ToastContainer position="top-center" pauseOnHover="false"/>

</div>
  )
}

// Getting the records // reading the data

export async function getServerSideProps() {
 
const res = await fetch("http://localhost:8000/api/post")
const data = await res.json()

return{
  props: {
    data
  }
}
}
```

Note : Pleae change `http://localhost:8000` as your laravle url and `http://localhost:3000` as per your frontend url.

The above solution worked for me.

Comment: I've done all of those steps and it still does not work on production. It works on local dev only. My laravel backend and NextJS frontend are on two different domains.

Comment: should we fetch sanctum/csrf-cookie before doing post method on all enpoints?

Answer (score 1):

Try changing the middleware from `web` to `api`.

```
Route::group(['middleware' => ['api']], function () {

    // our routes

});
```

Comment: tried. but not fixed the problem. is there any wasy to get and add laravel csrf token ?

Answer (score 1):

If you don't have the csrf token in your frontend, and want to disable the check on that specific route, you need to add the route to **$except** array in your **App\Http\Middleware\VerifyCsrfToken.php** class:

```
<?php namespace App\Http\Middleware;

use Illuminate\Foundation\Http\Middleware\VerifyCsrfToken as BaseVerifier;

class VerifyCsrfToken extends BaseVerifier
{
  protected $except = [
    'your route here',
  ];
}
```

Comment: how i can get the laravel csrf in the next js frontend, if i want to get and pass using the form / axios header.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know Nextjs, but basically you can put Laravel CSRF token at HTML document meta tag like this

```
<meta name="csrf-token" content="{{ csrf_token() }}" />
```

then you can access it using plain javascript like this

```
var csrf = document.querySelector('meta[name="csrf-token"]').content;
```